# How to pass props from different component(about and contact)? not parent to child. Using react typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Im trying to reused the about component to contact component. but i can't pass the data using props. when i debug it the props is undefined. and sometime the error is map undefined.

Here is my code

"ABOUT COMPONENT"
about.tsx

```
enum Color {
  Black = 'Black',
  Red = 'Red'
}

type aboutProps = {
items: string, 
backgroundColor: Color, 
minimumHeight: number, 
justify: string, 
align: string, 
fullWidth: boolean
}

const AboutComponent: FC<aboutProps> = ({items, backgroundColor, minimumHeight, justify, align, 
fullWidth}: aboutProps) => { return (
<>
<aboutContainer>
<div>
{items.map(({ heading, url, openInNewWindow, fontColor }) => {
return ( 
    <Text {...props}
    fontColor={fontColor}
    text={heading}
    url={url}
    openInNewWindow={openInNewWindow}                             
    dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: heading }}/>
    )
})}
</div>
</aboutContainer>
<>
)
}; 
export default AboutComponent;

"CONTACT COMPONENT"
contact.tsx

interface aboutProps {
items: string, 
backgroundColor: Color, 
minimumHeight: number, 
justify: string, 
align: string, 
fullWidth: boolean
}

interface contactProps extends aboutProps {
phone?: number,
name?: string,
}

const ContactComponent: FC<contactProps> = ({items, backgroundColor, minimumHeight, justify, align, fullWidth, phone, name}: contactProps) => { 

return (
    <>
     <AboutComponent items={items}
      backgroundColor = {backgroundColor}
      minimumHeight = {minimumHeight}
      justify = {justify}
      align = {align}
      fullWidth = {fullWidth}/>
    </>
)

};

export default ContactComponent;
```

**The props is undefined such as items, background, minimumHeight, justify, align, fullWidth**

Comment: Are you passing all of the correct props when you call <ContactComponent />?

Comment: Your types say that items is a string, but your code treats it as an array of objects { heading, url, openInNewWindow, fontColor }.

Answer (score 0):

It *is* a parent-child relationship.  I don't know why you think it's not. `ContactComponent` is the parent and `AboutComponent` is the child.

`ContactComponent` requires that it be called with all of the props of `AboutComponent` and you are passing them down correctly.  If you are getting errors that the props are `undefined` then that problem isn't in the code you've posted here.  It's that you are calling `<ContactComponent/>` without the right props.

---

But there are a lot of other problems.  The most glaring one is the prop `items` -- your types say that it is a `string`, but your code treats it as an `array` of objects with properties `{ heading, url, openInNewWindow, fontColor }`. You need to either A) require that you have an array of these objects or B) use the [`children` prop](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#children-in-jsx) and call your `AboutComponent` with `<Text/>` elements inside of it.

You don't want to use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` and you really don't need it.  It doesn't do anything here unless your `Text` component is taking this prop and using it.  It looks like your `Text` is already taking a `text` prop so it can create its own HTML content.

You might want to make some of the style props optional.  Right now they are all required.

This is my attempt to clean-up your components:

```
import React, { CSSProperties, FC } from "react";

export enum Color {
  // CSS color names are lower-case
  Black = "black",
  Red = "red"
}

export type TextProps = {
  text: string;
  url: string;
  openInNewWindow?: boolean;
  fontColor?: CSSProperties["color"];
};

export const Text: FC<TextProps> = ({
  text,
  url,
  openInNewWindow = false,
  fontColor
}) => {
  return (
    <a
      href={url}
      target={openInNewWindow ? "_blank" : "_self"}
      style={{ color: fontColor, display: "block", padding: 10 }}
    >
      {text}
    </a>
  );
};

export type AboutContainerProps = {
  backgroundColor?: Color;
  minimumHeight?: number;
  justify?: string;
  align?: string;
  fullWidth?: boolean;
};

export const AboutContainer: FC<AboutContainerProps> = ({
  backgroundColor = Color.Black,
  minimumHeight,
  justify = "space-evenly",
  align = "center",
  fullWidth = true,
  children // the JSX children -- this prop is automatically included by FC
}) => {
  return (
    <div
      style={{
        background: backgroundColor,
        minHeight: minimumHeight,
        width: fullWidth ? "100%" : "auto",
        display: "flex",
        justifyContent: justify,
        alignItems: align
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </div>
  );
};

export type AboutProps = AboutContainerProps & {
  items: TextProps[];
};

export const AboutComponent: FC<AboutProps> = ({
  items,
  ...aboutProps // rest object for all other props
}: AboutProps) => {
  return (
    <AboutContainer {...aboutProps}>
      {items.map((props) => {
        return <Text key={props.text} {...props} />;
      })}
    </AboutContainer>
  );
};

export type ContactInfo = {
  phone?: number;
  name?: string;
};

export const ContactInfoComponent: FC<ContactInfo> = ({ phone, name }) => {
  if (!phone && !name) {
    return null;
  }
  //TODO: format phone number string
  return (
    <div>
      <h3>Get In Touch</h3>
      {name && <div>{name}</div>}
      {phone && <div>Call Me: {phone}</div>}
    </div>
  );
};

export type ContactProps = AboutProps & ContactInfo;

// do we really even need this component?  can't we just compose it from the other two?
export const ContactComponent: FC<ContactProps> = ({
  phone,
  name,
  ...aboutProps
}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <ContactInfoComponent phone={phone} name={name} />
      <AboutComponent {...aboutProps} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

[Code Sandbox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/composing-react-components-3klmc?file=/src/App-v1.tsx)

With that sort of setup you call it like this, where `items` is an array of props objects.

```
const Test = () => (
  <ContactComponent
    minimumHeight={100}
    justify="flex-end"
    align="center"
    items={[
      {
        text: "Home",
        url: "/"
      },
      {
        text: "Facebook",
        url: "some link",
        openInNewWindow: true,
        fontColor: Color.Red
      }
    ]}
    name={"My Name"}
    phone={5555555555}
  />
);
```

This makes sense if the data is coming in a raw form from a database or API.  But if you are writing out props yourself you probably want to call it using modular pieces:

```
const Test = () => (
  <div>
    <ContactInfoComponent name={"My Name"} phone={5555555555} />
    <AboutContainer
      minimumHeight={100}
      justify="flex-end"
      align="center"
      fullWidth={false}
    >
      <Text url="/">Home</Text>
      <Text url="some link" openInNewWindow={true} fontColor={Color.Red}>
        Facebook
      </Text>
    </AboutContainer>
  </div>
);
```

So you would make use of the [`children` prop](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#children-in-jsx) rather than passing props down multiple levels.

```
import React, { CSSProperties, FC } from "react";

export enum Color {
  // CSS color names are lower-case
  Black = "black",
  Red = "red"
}

export type TextProps = {
  url: string;
  openInNewWindow?: boolean;
  fontColor?: CSSProperties["color"];
};

export const Text: FC<TextProps> = ({
  children,
  url,
  openInNewWindow = false,
  fontColor
}) => {
  return (
    <a
      href={url}
      target={openInNewWindow ? "_blank" : "_self"}
      style={{ color: fontColor, display: "block", padding: 10 }}
    >
      {children}
    </a>
  );
};

export type AboutContainerProps = {
  backgroundColor?: Color;
  minimumHeight?: number;
  justify?: string;
  align?: string;
  fullWidth?: boolean;
};

export const AboutContainer: FC<AboutContainerProps> = ({
  backgroundColor = Color.Black,
  minimumHeight,
  justify = "space-evenly",
  align = "center",
  fullWidth = true,
  children // the JSX children -- this prop is automatically included by FC
}) => {
  return (
    <div
      style={{
        background: backgroundColor,
        minHeight: minimumHeight,
        width: fullWidth ? "100%" : "auto",
        display: "flex",
        justifyContent: justify,
        alignItems: align
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </div>
  );
};

export type ContactInfo = {
  phone?: number;
  name?: string;
};

export const ContactInfoComponent: FC<ContactInfo> = ({ phone, name }) => {
  if (!phone && !name) {
    return null;
  }
  //TODO: format phone number string
  return (
    <div>
      <h3>Get In Touch</h3>
      {name && <div>{name}</div>}
      {phone && <div>Call Me: {phone}</div>}
    </div>
  );
};
```

This code is mostly the same but we can actually delete a few of the components.

[Code Sandbox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/composing-react-components-3klmc?file=/src/App-v2.tsx)